# php array replacement

Tags: php, arrays, replace, restructuredtext

This is a array problem

if I have this `$URI = 'http://localhost/id/artikel/info_artikel/1141/'`
I would like to use `$filterURL = explode('/', $URI);` to split this url 
then replace specific value as like the following:

```
        $filter = str_replace('id', 'en', $filterURL[3]);
        $sectionname_translated = str_replace($value, $key, $filterURL[4]);
        $filterfilename = explode('?', $filterURL[5]);
        $filename = $filterfilename[0];
        $newfilename = str_replace($filename, 'articles', $filename);
```

how can I restructure back the replaced array value with the origin `$filterURL`? Because the number of array might be vary, but only this number of array need to do replacement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? i.e. before and after cases? May be a cleaner way to do it

Comment: Not sure I am following you, but if you just want to rebuild a URL from an array, you can use implode('/', $filterURL);

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have various functions like [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for handling url.

For example:

```
$URI = 'http://localhost/something/index.php?test1=var1&test2=var2';
$parseUrl = parse_url($URI);
parse_str($parseUrl['query'], $parseUrl['query']);

array
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  'path' => string '/something/index.php' (length=20)
  'query' => 
    array
     'test1' => string 'var1' (length=4)
     'test2' => string 'var2' (length=4)
```

Then you can revert the process:

```
$parseUrl['query'] = http_build_query($parseUrl['query']);
$parseUrl = http_build_url($parseUrl);
```

As for reverting explode process it is like **m_w** said [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).